# Naive implementation of sort inplace

Tags: python, beginner, sorting, homework

I had the following assignment for the Python 101 course I'm taking in my university.

```
'''
Modify the naive implementation (see below) of a sorting algorithm so that
the list to be sorted is modified *in place*.

Here is the idea:

1. Iterate over all indices i = 0, 1, 2, ... of the input list

2. Find the index j of the smallest element in the rest of the list (from i on)

3. Replace the elements at indices i and j

If we want to sort the list [5, 3, 1, 4, 8, 2, 7, 6], for instance, a run of
the algorithm would be:

i=0, j=2, list=[5, 3, 1, 4, 8, 2, 7, 6]
i=1, j=5, list=[1, 3, 5, 4, 8, 2, 7, 6]
i=2, j=5, list=[1, 2, 5, 4, 8, 3, 7, 6]
i=3, j=3, list=[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 5, 7, 6]
i=4, j=5, list=[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 5, 7, 6]
i=5, j=7, list=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 7, 6]
i=6, j=6, list=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
'''
```

In principle, the only two funcions I have to modify are "index_of_smallest_element" and "naive_sort_inplace".

```
def index_of_smallest_element(some_list):
    '''Returns the index of the smallest element in some_list'''
    guess=some_list[0]    
    for element in some_list:
        if element < guess:
            guess=element
    return some_list.index(guess)


def naive_sort(some_list):
    sorted_list = []
    while len(some_list) > 0:
        # remove smallest element from some_list
        smallest_element = some_list.pop(index_of_smallest_element(some_list))
        # ... and append it to sorted_list
        sorted_list.append(smallest_element)
    return sorted_list


def naive_sort_inplace(some_list):
    def exchange(some_list,x,y):
        some_list[x],some_list[y]=some_list[y],some_list[x]        


    for i in range(0,len(some_list)):        
        remaining_list=some_list[i:(len(some_list)+1)]
        i_rest=index_of_smallest_element(remaining_list)
        j=i+i_rest
        print('i=',i,'j=',j,'list=',some_list)
        exchange(some_list,i,j)
    return some_list


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_list = [5, 3, 1, 4, 8, 2, 7, 6]
    naive_sort_inplace(my_list)
    print('Test: ', my_list == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

Although the code is fully functional, I'm wondering is there would be a better way to do it, especially the "naive_sort_inplace" function.

Answer (score 1):

### Problems

First of all, your current implementation is not truly in-place, since the slice operation creates a new list of that size, which breaches the required max constant extra space usage.

In addition you perform double work in the `index_of_smallest_element` when you first find the value you want, and then have to run through the entire list again to find the index (the index call has linear time cost)

### Advise

When working in-place you usually have to work with indexes or pointers, and this is also such a case. Most of the work can be put into 3 categories, index work, swapping work, and control flow, if you are doing work outside of those you should think through an extra time on whether you are off in a problematic direction.

This means that you should manually keep track of relevant indexes, and when calling functions the way to work on a subset is to pass the indexes describing this to it.

### Solution

there are 2 main changes to be done, both connected to `index_of_smallest_element`. We first change thats implementation to the following:

```
def index_of_smallest_element(some_list, start=0):
    smallest = some_list[start]
    for i in range(start+1, len(some_list)):
       value = some_list[I]
       if value < smallest:
           smallest = value
           start = i
    return start
```

With this it becomes easy to write the naive (and really bad) sorting in-place:

```
def naive_sort_inplace(some_list, out=None):
    def exchange(some_list,x,y):
        some_list[x],some_list[y]=some_list[y],some_list[x]        


    for i in range(0,len(some_list)):
        j = index_of_smallest_element(remaining_list, i)
        if out is not None:
            out('i=',i,'j=',j,'list=',some_list)
        exchange(some_list,i,j)
    return some_list
```

I am not quite sure why you want to do all the printing, but I assume it is for testing or proving correctness. For reuse I have changed it so it by default does not print, but if you pass in `print` (or some other output function such as `open(filename,'w').write`) then it write those log updates to that output function.